# C# - Passing C# Variable to JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, string

I have the following line of code in C#:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Transaction_Number.aspx?num=<%=trans_number%>', '_newtab')", true);
```

Now, trans_number is a variable in my C# code-behind.  My problem is that when I process the query string (num variable), the result is always:

```
<%trans_number%>
```

instead of the contents of that variable.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you can resolve this pretty easily... Maybe:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Transaction_Number.aspx?num=" + trans_number + "', '_newtab')", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a string that concatenates with a variable and is in turn embedded within another string. Issues like this tend to go away when you use intermediate variables and `String.Format` method:

```
string url = String.Format(@"http://localhost:4000/Transaction_Number.aspx?num={0}", trans_number);
string js = String.Format("window.open('{0}', '_newtab')", url);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, js, true);
```